# getting lowest available column number for insert postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-insert

I have a application where I want clothing groups to be assigned to a rack number. The rack number should be as low as possible, and the groups are frequently replaced (recycled clothing). So how would I find the lowest possible `rack_number` on the following table?

`clothing_groups` table

`[ id: sequal, rack_number:  smallint ]`

Currently we are retrieving an ascended list of all `rack_numbers` iterating through them to find the first gap, and using it for the insertion of the next `clothing_groups`

```sql
SELECT
    rack_number
FROM
    clothing_groups
ORDER BY
    rack_number ASC;
```

Which seems to be suboptimal at best, I'd rather either retrieve a single row or preferrably do a subquery within the insert finding the first available `rack_number`

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    clothing_groups (rack_number)
VALUES
   SELECT first_available_rack_number FROM clothing_groups WHERE ...
```

However I do not know if or how it is possible.

Any combination of rack_number rows is possible with gaps. That means it is possible for the sequence to be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,12,14..., 231,432,500]` and it changes dynamically based on the deletions and insertions. The only thing that is guaranteed is that there exists a "missing" number lower than 999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
INSERT INTO clothing_groups (rack_number)
SELECT MIN(rack_number) + 1
FROM clothing_groups cg
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM clothing_groups cg1 WHERE cg1.rack_number = cg.rack_number + 1)
```

You could also use window functions:

```
INSERT INTO clothing_groups (rack_number)
SELECT MIN(rack_number) + 1
FROM (
    SELECT rack_number, LEAD(rack_number) OVER(ORDER BY rack_number) lead_rack_number
    FROM clothing_groups
) cg
WHERE lead_rack_number IS DISTINCT FROM rack_number + 1
```

Comment: Both options seem to return the value below the lowest possible value. I have unmarked the answer

Comment: @JonasGrønbek: I think this is just missing `+1`. Done